# How to read S3 XML files query using Hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hive, hiveql, emr

I've XML files stored in AWS S3 bucket. I want to extract XML metadata and load in HIVE Tables on HDFS. Is there any tool, which can help to expediate this activity?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might need to use HIVE XML SerDe's to read the XML files or write/use Custom UDF's that can understand XML.

Some references that might help : https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/972/hive-and-xml-pasring.html
https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/47840/how-do-i-do-xml-string-parsing-in-hive.html

Comment: with the help of hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar managed to extract data from XML.

Comment: great  @ Pawan !